# Display vertices of object and rotate object with Three.js, WebGL

Tags: three.js

I have added a pyramid mesh into the scene and I can rotate it about the x, y and z axes individually.

What I need to do is add an object to the scene that is 5 coloured dots to represent the 5 vertices of the pyramid, and then rotate this object.

I know the coordinates of the vertices but I'm not sure how I would implement this. To rotate the pyramid mesh I am using mesh.rotation.x, mesh.rotation.y, mesh.rotation.z.

Should I maybe try to create a custom mesh containing the 5 vertices and use mesh.rotation, or is a different approach easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual approach for solving this issue is to add the coloured dots as child objects to your pyramid. If you then rotate the pyramid, the dots will rotate to (because the keep their position relative to their parent).

The position of the colored dots are the coordinates of the respective pyramid vertices.

Comment: Okay thanks. I didn't make this very clear in the question but if I want to display the vertices of the pyramid, I need to remove the original pyramid mesh from the scene. So I can display the pyramid in "faces mode" or "vertex mode". Would this method still work in this case, as I'd be trying to rotate an object that has been removed from the scene?

Comment: Instead of removing the pyramid, set the [visible](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/materials/Material.visible) property of its material to `false`. It should then work as expected.